# Scroll in design view for metro style app in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

I am working on a metro style app (XAML) in Visual Studio 2012.  I am building a form that flows vertically on the screen that the user will have to scroll.  I would like to be able to see the form in design view but after it exceeds the height of the screen I can't see the changes I am adding anymore and I have to run the app to see the layout.  Is there a way to scroll in design view as you are working?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DesignHeight` & `DesignWidth` property, if you want to stretch the current page in design mode.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="1768"
    d:DesignWidth="2366">

<!-- Other XAML Controls -->

</Page>
```